# SELECT title of movie and all actors of this

Tags: mysql

I have database which score movies and actors. And I need to select title of movies and all this actors. I create next query:

```
SELECT movies.title, CONCAT_WS(' ', actors.name, actors.surname) as Actor FROM movies                LEFT JOIN movies_actors 
ON movies.id = movies_actors.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN actors 
ON actors.id = movies_actors.actor_id
```

And I get something that:

```
+------------------------------+--------------+
| title                        | actor        |
+------------------------------+--------------+
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Eva Green    |
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Bruce Willis |
+------------------------------+--------------+
```

But I want to get something this:

```
+------------------------------+--------------+
| title                        | actor        |
+------------------------------+--------------+
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Eva Green    |
|                              | Bruce Willis |
+------------------------------+--------------+
```

I try to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT movies.title...
```

but it doesn't help.

Can you help me? Thanks! 
This is my database

```
CREATE TABLE movies ( 
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    title VARCHAR(255),
    director VARCHAR(255), 
    created DATE, 
    budget DECIMAL(12,2), 
    box_office DECIMAL(13,2), 
    duration TIME 
)

 CREATE TABLE actors (
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   surname VARCHAR(255),
   name VARCHAR(255),
   birthday DATE
 )

ALTER TABLE movies_actors
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies (id)
ALTER TABLE movies_actors
  ADD FOREIGN KEY FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actors (id)

INSERT INTO 'movies' 
    (`id`, `title`, `director`, `created`, `budget`, `box_office`, `duration`) 
VALUES 
    (1, 'Sin City: A Dame to Kill For', 'Frank Miller, Robert Anthony Rodriguez',                          '2014', 62000000.00, 38000000.00, '01:42:00')

INSERT INTO `actors` 
    (`id`, `surname`, `name`, `birthday`) 
VALUES
    (1, 'Green', 'Eva', '1980-07-06'),
    (2, 'Willis', 'Bruce', '1955-03-19')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT movies.title, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(concat(actors.name, ' ', actors.surname)) as Actors
FROM movies                
LEFT JOIN movies_actors ON movies.id = movies_actors.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN actors ON actors.id = movies_actors.actor_id
GROUP BY movies.title
```

Answer (score 0):

After a join, you always get a result foreach column cell, if there is a valid value. So, when you find 2 valid actors in the join, the title will be repeated 2 times, as you already noticed.

```
+------------------------------+--------------+
| title                        | actor        |
+------------------------------+--------------+
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Eva Green    |
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Bruce Willis |
+------------------------------+--------------+
```

You could concat the result for the actor and group by title ofc, to get something like this:

```
+------------------------------+-------------------------+
| title                        | actor                   |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Sin City: A Dame to Kill For | Eva Green,Bruce Willis  |
+------------------------------+-------------------------+

SELECT 
  movies.title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(concat(actors.name, ' ', actors.surname)) as Actor 
FROM 
  movies                
LEFT JOIN 
   movies_actors ON movies.id = movies_actors.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN 
   actors ON actors.id = movies_actors.actor_id
GROUP BY movies.title
```